# manipulate json data in python

Tags: python, json

Being a python newbie I am having trouble understanding json data handeling in python. For example how can I convert the following data

```
[<OldSample {u'counter_name': u'cpu_util', u'user_id': u'id', u'resource_id': u'id', u'timestamp': u'2015-06-30T15:53:55', u'counter_volume': 0.043}]
```

into  something like this in python

```
[ { time: 2015-06-30T15:53:55, counter_volume: 0.043 },
  { time: 2015-06-30T15:53:56, counter_volume: 0.045 }]
```

I am trying the following code:

```
def clean_Json(data):
  for each in data:
    timetamp = each.timestamp
    volume =  each.counter_volume
    r= json.dumps({'timetamp': timestamp, 'volume': volume})

clean_Json(data)
```

But it gives me error:
NameError: `global name 'timestamp' is not defined`

Comment: Check your spelling. Your third line says  "timetamp".

Comment: I guess what @TheBigH said solves your problem.